# Tabindex is not working?

Tags: html

I've been reading the documentation of how to apply the tabindex feature in HTML to elements and I'm trying to add it to the "empty-btn" button in my HTML below but the tabbing feature goes straight to my social media icons instead. Why is this? How do I fix this so that it tabs on the button before the icons?

HTML

```
   <p class="designations">
                            <%= profile.designations %>
                                            <button type="button" class="empty-btn" tabindex="0">
                                                    <div class="designations-popup">
                                                            <div class="popup-content">
                                                                    <h5><%- theme_data.designation_pop_title %></h5>
                                                            <p><%- theme_data.designation_pop_msg %></p>
                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>
                                            </button>
                    </p>
                <% } %>
                                    <h2 itemprop="jobTitle">
                                            <%= theme_data.job_title.replace(/(®)/ig, "<sup>$1</sup>") %>
                                    </h2>
                            </section>
                                    <% if (profile.networks) { %>
                                            <!-- Social Icons -->
                                            <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs pull-right social-icons">
                                                    <% if (profile.networks.facebook_url ) { %>
                                                    <a href="<%- profile.networks.facebook_url %>" target="_blank">
                                                            <img alt="Facebook Logo" src="./images/facebook.png">
                                                    </a>
                                                    <% } %>
                                                    <% if (profile.networks.twitter_url ) { %>
                                                    <a href="<%- profile.networks.twitter_url %>" target="_blank">
                                                            <img alt="Twitter Logo" src="./images/twitter.png">
                                                    </a>
                                                    <% } %>
                                                    <% if (profile.networks.linkedin_url ) { %>
                                                    <a href="<%- profile.networks.linkedin_url %>" target="_blank">
                                                            <img alt="LinkedIn Logo" src="./images/linkedin.png">
                                                    </a>
                                                    <% } %>
                                            </div>
                                    <% } %>
```

Comment: Please try to format your code in a way that makes it easier to read,

Comment: And what `tabindex` value do your social media icons have?

Comment: Further more only phrasing content is permitted inside the `button` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) and you should probably read: http://adrianroselli.com/2014/11/dont-use-tabindex-greater-than-0.html which will explain what `tabindex="0"` does,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue properly your question is more to set the focus on the button rather than tab order. Since there is so much dynamic content in your page I think it makes sense to set the focus on the element you wish to get selected first. You can also remove tabindex=0 and leave the tab ordering to browser (unless you want a really jumbled up tab order).

tabindex property can only assist you to set the element's position in tabbing order but it will not help you to focus on a particular element.

Comment: How do I get it to focus on the button using the tab button on the keyboard with my code?

Comment: Also, can this possibly be solved using JS instead? Ideally I'd don't want to.

Comment: I am not really clear what you meant by "focus on the button using the tab button on the keyboard with my code". Give an ID to your button and just call `.focus()`

Comment: You don't even need tabindex to do that: https://jsfiddle.net/d0c65j6L/1/. Focus on the frame with the rendered page and hit tab. Your button gets focus.